# Configure annotate Intellij command for SVN integration

Tags: svn, intellij-idea

Is it possible to configure "annotate" action in Intellij SVN integration to ignore white spaces ([svn blame -x](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.ref.svn.c.blame.html)) ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to make SVN ignore whitespaces when running blame/annotate/praise in IntelliJ IDEA.

1. Start IDEA.
2. Navigate to **File | Settings | Version Control | Subversion**.
3. Select **Presentation** tab.
4. Enable **Ignore whitespace differences in annotations**.

Check IDEAs documentation for more info:

> [**Ignore whitespace differences in annotations**](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.3/subversion.html#d1885868e180)
>
> Select this check box if you want white spaces to be ignored when
>   annotating, and, thus, get more meaningful annotations and cast out
>   senseless ones.

BTW, you could easily find this option without leaving the IDE -- enter a keyword that could belong to the option that you look for into Search field. Search by options should be available on Preferences and Options dialogs. I guess that searching for `whitespace` could help in this case.

It seems that I made a research that you could easily do yourself. Quick web search reveals this ticket [IDEA-48913: Add ability to ignore whitespace with SVN blame - annotate](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-48913) with instructions. :)